# Scaling VectorDrawables on Varying Resolutions

Tags: android

## Background

I am currently working on creating a map with pins. For the marker and pins, we are using VectorDrawables. Our issue is with obtaining an ideal scale for the marker/pins on all devices in relation to the map. What is the best practice for handling vector scaling on multiple devices?

**Note:** For this question, we are only concerned with Lollipop or greater devices as we are planning on updating to the latest support library which provides support for VectorDrawables.

**Images**:
To demonstrate this, I have included a picture that is close to the ideal size. I do have another photo showing what it looks like on tablets, but unfortunately I am only allowed to post one link at this time.

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twWcr.png)] As viewed on an S6: This is an ideal size, but the difficulty is obtaining it for all devices.

[Map Marker/Pins on Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twWcr.png)

---

### Code

Most of what determines the overlay size is handled by the marker code and its associated vector file, but I will supply more code if needed.

**Adding Overlay:**

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    // Draw backgrounds
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //set up the color and the mode for the filtering function
    //        paint.setColorFilter(cf);

    // Draw overlays
    for (ImageOverlay overlay : this.overlayList)
    {
        Matrix overlayMatrix = overlay.getTranslationMatrix();

        if (overlay.getIsScalable())
        {
            overlayMatrix.postConcat(getImageMatrix());
        }
        else
        {
            float[] vals = new float[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            getImageMatrix().getValues(vals);
            float scaleDx = overlay.getX() - (vals[Matrix.MSCALE_X]*overlay.getX());
            float scaleDy = overlay.getY() - (vals[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]*overlay.getY());
            overlayMatrix.postTranslate(vals[Matrix.MTRANS_X]-scaleDx, vals[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]-scaleDy);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay.getImage(), overlayMatrix, paint);
    }
}
```

**Marker Code:**

```
 /**
 * This method creates a bitmap for the mapMarker that we use to show where the customer is located on the map.
 * @return Returns a bitmap of the marker.
 */
private Bitmap buildMapMarker(){
    // Display the marker for that company
    Bitmap mapMarkerBitmap;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        VectorDrawable mapMarkerVectorDrawable = (VectorDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_place_red_24dp);
        mapMarkerBitmap = getOverlayBitmap(mapMarkerVectorDrawable, 79);
    } else {
        mapMarkerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_place_red_24dp);
    }

    return mapMarkerBitmap;
}

/**
 * This method is used to obtain the overlay bitmap for devices that are >= API 21.
 * @param vectorDrawable Passed vectorDrawable to obtain info from.
 * @return
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private Bitmap getOverlayBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable, int width) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
            width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

**Marker Vector XML:**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:pathData="M12,2C8.13,2 5,5.13 5,9c0,5.25 7,13 7,13s7,-7.75 7,-13c0,-3.87 -3.13,-7 -7,-7zm0,9.5c-1.38,0 -2.5,-1.12 -2.5,-2.5s1.12,-2.5 2.5,-2.5 2.5,1.12 2.5,2.5 -1.12,2.5 -2.5,2.5z"
    android:fillColor="#F44336"/>
```

**Attempts I have made:**

1. Using the vectors own dpi width/height ratio, this resulted in the markers being too large on higher dpi devices such as the s6 and small on devices such as the Nexus 7
2. Setting a fixed width and height for the canvas, this resulted in a much larger marker on low dpi devices vs high dpi devices.
3. Initially, we made individual pngs for each device and this was the most ideal solution thus far, but we were hoping to implement vectors in some way if possible.

**Note:**
Please let me know if more information or code is needed to provide a sufficient response.

Comment: Well, since you know the position of where the markers are on a scaled map, you should technically know the scale of the map versus its original size. So, why not set the marker's size to a percentage of the width of the scaled map, as to always have it's size scale with the map?

Comment: Good point. I forgot to mention, but I have tried that approach as well, but maybe my logic was flawed. I attempted to use DisplayMetrics to get the width of the screen in pixels and then divided it by 1/8 to get a certain width in pixels, and then setting that as the bounds for my canvas.

Comment: On second thought, I may have misread in my first comment, but I will leave it here for future reference. I see what you are saying, so use the map's scaling as reference rather than the device's scaling. That sounds pretty valid. I will attempt that tomorrow and follow up with my results.